# Check if cookie exists not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using the below code to check if a cookie exists with a certain value then do something.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if (document.cookie.indexOf('samplename=itsvalue')== -1 ) {
      alert("cookie");
   }
});
```

It always displays the alert whether the cookie exists or not. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Original response:

Unless you have a cookie with the key "samplename=itsvalue", your code will always evaluate to true. If the key is "samplename" and the value is "itsvalue", you should rewrite the check like this:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('samplename') == -1 ) {
  alert("cookie");
}
```

This will tell you that the cookie does not exist.

To see if it does exist:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('samplename') > -1 ) {
  alert("cookie exists");
}
```

**Updating to better address this question:**

What you are looking for in that check will always evaluate to true and throw the alert. Add the following function to your js and call it to check if your cookie exists.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookie = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = cookie.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = cookie.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    } else {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = cookie.length;
        }
    }
    return unescape(cookie.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
```

You can then check your cookies with the following:

```
var myCookie = getCookie("samplename");

if (myCookie == null) {
    alert("cookie does not exist");
} else {
    alert("cookie exists");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the update too! I really appreciate it. I tested with your previous code (before the update) and it worked perfectly, so thank you again. I will take this as an accepted answer as it solved my problem. Perhaps it would be nice if you added your previous code again beside the new one as an alternative solution for anyone having the same issue. Here it is `if (document.cookie.indexOf('samplename') > -1 ) { alert("cookie"); }`  Greetings!

Comment: @JerryB I will add my previous code back in. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: `dc is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');//contains all the cookies
var cookieName = []; // to contain name of all the cookies

for(i=0;i<cookies.length;i++) {
    cookieName[i] = cookies[i].split('=')[0].trim();
}

    if(cookiesName.indexOf(cookieNameYouAreLookingFor)>-1) {
        console.log("EXISTS");
    } else {
        console.log("DOESN'T EXIST");
    }
```

Paste this code in browser console and check.